# substitute for missing patio umbrella parts

Tags: outdoor, patio

I have a weighted patio umbrella base in which you insert a curved metal piece and then tighten the umbrella into place by hand-twisting a bolt into place.  I seem to have lost the metal insert and the bolt during the move from my last house.  The bolt is easy enough to find a replacement, but I can't seem to find anything that fits the bill to replace the curved metal piece.  I have found some rubber inserts on Amazon, but these aren't big enough for my umbrella's 2 inch diameter pole.  I have reached out to the manufacturer for a replacement part and they have been no help.  I'm struggling to understand why this metal insert is so difficult to find given that most umbrella bases use a similar design to secure the umbrella pole into place.  Anyone know where I can find a good replacement or substitute piece?  I've circled the two pieces in question.  I just can't seem to find a replacement for the metal hook portion that sits in the base.

[image]

Comment: is the idea that you tighten the bolt and it pushes the long side of the metal saddle against the pole?

Comment: I'm not clear on what that part does, either. Is the nut held captive by it? Photos might help. My initial hunch is that a regular nut and a toothed lock washer might do the trick.

Comment: yes, the bolt pushes the metal saddle against the umbrella pole to keep it in place... the idea is that the metal saddle is a strong metal the bolt can press against and distribute the pressure against the pole so as to not damage the pole itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the clip is to spread out the pressure a bit between the end of the bolt and the shaft of the umbrella. That'll provide more friction and make it harder for a gust of wind to yank the umbrella up and out. And it'll also prevent the end of the bolt from digging in to the shaft. That said, the precise shape and material is unlikely to be critical to the general function.

### Replacement?

My searches have failed to find any similar bases, with or without replacement parts availability. You appear to have an image from a manual, so reaching out to the manufacturer might help, as would adding their name to a search query.

### Substitute?

As the exact size and shape aren't likely to be critical, you should be able to fabricate something from similar material. Ideally, it would be something that would hold up to exterior conditions. Scanning the mental inventory of the leftover bits and pieces that I have lying around, the first thing I'd try is an old license plate. Cut a piece about the right size. Looks like about 3/4" wide by about 5" long. Drill a hole slightly larger than the retaining bolt near one end. Then bend it, leaving the short segment just large enough to account for the curvature of the tube.

Comment: Yeah, the first thing I did was reach out to the manufacturer and they've been less than helpful unfortunately... basically told me they can't send me the part... I like your idea though, I'll just go ahead and try bending some metal to fit the slot